# Unable to remove faucet handle to replace cartridge

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

Our kitchen faucet has started leaking right through the handle, so it sounds like it's a cartridge problem. I'm trying to remove the handle and when I remove the set screw ([looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/8m2oHk5)), I can't pull the handle out. Nothing changes to be honest - even if I try to force it out with strong pulls it doesn't move at all. Either something is royally stuck or I don't know what the screw is holding together. I assumed this was just a "pull it out" motion, but I also tried rotation and pulling and nothing budges. Is there any other movement I should try?

Comment: Be sure the set screw is completely removed. Try using a screwdriver between the underside of the handle and the body and pry up.  There is just some corrosion and calcium buildup holding that handle that must be overcome.

Comment: Something like PB Blaster might be useful to break up corrosion, too. Caveat: PB Blaster may not be the thing you want to spray around your kitchen - clean thoroughly if you do.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. After reading around I realized this was a common occurence and felt a bit more secure putting more force into my pulls. It ended up coming out eventually.